# Polynomial relation between two complex numbers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$ such that,
$$\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt{y}=1$$
show that $x$ and $y$ satisfy the polynomial relation,
$$x^2-2x-6xy-y^3+3y^2-3y+1=0$$
I guess you could simply do $y=(1-\sqrt[3]x)^2$ and make a substitution, but is there any more elegant way?

Comment: What is  the polynomial relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$y-1=(\sqrt{x}+1)(\sqrt{x}-1)=x^{\frac 23}-2x^{\frac 13}$$
Hence$$(y-1)^3=x^2-6x^{\frac 53}+12x^{\frac 43}-8x$$
$$\Rightarrow (y-1)^3-x^2+2x=-6x^{\frac 53}+12x^{\frac 43}-6x=-6x(x^{\frac 23}-2x^{\frac 13}+1)=-6xy$$ QED

Comment: Awesome, did you use any particular method?

Comment: No I just observed that the last four terms are the binomial expansion of $(y-1)^3$